# Can I replace 'have not' or 'haven't' with 'ain't' in oral English?

Tags: informal-language

In an English [lesson](https://youtu.be/9Z8JqutRWrs?t=91), the teacher said,

> I ain't been to Jamaica.

Obviously, she replaced 'haven't' by 'ain't'. If 'haven't' or 'have not' is used to form a perfect tense, can I always replace it with 'ain't' in oral English?

Comment: Yes, but to be honest, some people will look down on you for doing so. It depends on region and social class, but there are definitely still those who will consider "ain't" less correct and less acceptable, even orally.

Comment: @rjpond Does that apply to 'ain't' that replaces 'be not'? In many American movies about the wild west, the cowboys seem to do this a lot.

Comment: "Always"?  No.  It's very much a dialect or informal version.  Grammatically, yes, it fits in the same places; culturally, no, you are choosing to speak a different dialect.  And you may be walking into a linguistic minefield - people might think you are making fun of them.

Comment: The use of *ain't* is not proper.  It does not follow English rules.  It can replace *have not, has not, are not, will not, is not, does not, and others*.  So if I say, *Bill ain't got the car fixed,* I mean has not.  If I say, *They ain't got the skills,* I mean *do not*.  Saying, *He ain't gonna do it,* means he *will not*. I agree that you DO NOT want to use the word *ain't*.  It ain't proper to do so and such.

Comment: @Michael It's pretty much equally deprecated whether it's used to mean "is/am/are not" or "have/has not".  If you were speaking standard (or "educated middle-class") British English, the only time you might say "ain't" would be in a few well-known expressions or sayings ("If it ain't broke, don't fix it"; "You ain't seen nothing yet").  Otherwise, it tends to be avoided entirely.  (I refer to British English here because it's the variety I'm most familiar with.)

Comment: My mother told me off for saying 'ain't'.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther I must quibble on a couple of minor points.  I would say that in "They ain't got the skills", "ain't" means "haven't".  (It's true that in American slang, one can also say "They don't got the skills", but my explanation seems a simpler way of parsing the sentence, since "ain't" can't replace "don't" in most sentences, e.g. we couldn't say "They ain't hate it.")  Similarly, in "He ain't gonna do it", "ain't" simply means "isn't".  It's true that "isn't gonna" means roughly the same as "won't", but again, "ain't" can't replace "won't" in general.

Comment: @rjpond - All good points but I would say that my parsing of ain't is 100% valid and accurate -- ain't got = don't got = does not have.   Once you accept *ain't got* you have to also accept *don't got*.  This demonstrates why ain't is not proper and should be avoided - no one knows what a person is saying when they say it.  And when they say it it does not have to follow any rules of grammar.  A person who says ain't could most certainly say, *They ain't hate it.*  Sounds like perfectly constructed *ain't talk* to me.  As I said, it's not proper.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther - I have to quibble with your statement that *ain't* "doesn't follow English rules" and "no one knows what a person is saying when they say it".  There is no "Official Academy of the English Language"; the rules of English are descriptive, not prescriptive.  In dialects where *ain't* is used, it absolutely does follow rules, and the speakers definitely know what is meant when it's said.

Comment: @stangdon - It would have been better to to say *unless you already use ain't* you probably don't know how to use it.  Think about rjpond's comment where he claims no one would say, *They ain't hate it*.  I have heard that very thing said to my face so rj's comment is incorrect. Now that I think about it, *if you don't currently use ain't you may have trouble using correctly,* is probably the best answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Agree with @strangdon. I've never been confused by someone saying "ain't." But I also don't recall hearing it used in any routine way by someone who's not a native (or native-level) speaker of the English language.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther That's very fair, and I can agree with that, which is why I would never recommend a learner use it until they are at a very high level of English learning and are ready to tackle the complicated issues involved.

Comment: I almost never hear *ain’t* here on the West Coast of the U.S.  It’s more common in some other accents, but it might sound odd to use it if it doesn’t match the accent your speech sounds most like.

Comment: This question hits home for me because I'm from the central US rural areas. The only time I have ever heard Ain't or used Ain't for that matter is without articles. It will sound more natural most times saying this instead. "I ain't been no Jamaica." or "She ain't here." or "They ain't got no talent." or "He ain't doin' nuthin' ever." But, it's probably best to just not use ain't it will sound really strange if you can't get the accent perfect.

Comment: This doesn't follow:  ain't got = don't got = does not have.  It's ain't got = don't got = does not got. @EllieK-Don'tsupporther the person that said 'They ain't hate it' simply wasn't using the colloquial rules *correctly*.  Are you sure it was 'they ain't haters'?  Also this sequence interests:  'A person who says ain't could most certainly say, They ain't hate it. Sounds like perfectly constructed ain't talk to me.'  and 'I have heard that very thing said to my face'.

Comment: @mcalex - They ain't hate it = They don't hate it.  If you're unfamiliar with that construct you may need to to expand your Horizons of Ain't.  Its usage ain't constrained to the hills of Appalachia.

Comment: +1 for the video, the teacher has an accent that reminds me of someone from the West-Indies living in London 40 years ago. "Ain't" was definitely cockney before the 1980s, and Londoners from the poorer working class boroughs would say it without consciously thinking about it. The teacher's accent seems an amalgamation of cockney and British Jamaican. I would not imitate it if I wanted to buy something in a shop or if I was invited to a restaurant. Never imitate a dialect unless you know it very well, but by itself "ain't" as in "I ain't dunnit" (I didn't do it) is easy enough to learn.

Comment: P.S 70% of the expressions in that video, even 80%  were totally foreign to me. There is some American influences,  I would need visual clues and context to understand half of it, e.g. *You bussin sick creps* = trainers. I would think they were talking about eating delicious French pancakes!

Comment: Unless your'e a 70 year old moonshiner talking about cleaning squirrel guns, you'll probably just sound like a schmuck.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther How unknowledgeable and classist and snobby can one sound? The teacher in the video explains very clearly its usage. You want to go and tell all the Londoners who use is they are not being proper??

Comment: @Lambie - I ain't listen to no teacher cause I ain't watched no video.  But I ain't ascairt to call no word unproper.  You ascairt?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Speaking descriptively, the facts are simple: This is a typical and long-established use of *ain't*.

Often, complaints against *ain't* have less to do with the sentence and more to do with the word itself.

---

Longer answer: *Ain't* [is used for various purposes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ain%27t#Etymology). It can be used for both *am not* and *have not* (as well as their other conjugations and contractions, e.g. *he ain't*, *they ain't*).

Some speakers only use it for *am not* ("I ain't a clown"), while others include *do not* ("I ain't go to church")<sup>1</sup> and even fold in the expletive subject *there* (making a full sentence of "Ain't no way over that bridge!").

But the main thing to remember is that **any use of "ain't" tends to be strongly proscribed because it is marked by region and social class**. As the Wikipedia article says, summarizing other authors, [ain't has been called the most stigmatized word and the most powerful social marker in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ain%27t#Proscription_and_stigma).

What's the nature of the stigma? Many speakers regard *ain't* as inherently ungrammatical or lowbrow. The word smacks of rurality and low education and unrefinement. It evokes [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English) and Southern and Midwestern US dialects in general (though in reality it is used more widely, including in England). It also often co-occurs with the double negative (*ain't no*) and other marked elements (e.g. *got* instead of *have*).

It's also heavily used in media representing characters from these regions and classes, reinforcing the above.

These perceptions are certainly not reasons why *ain't* is incorrect or bad, but they are

1. reasons for you to be aware of the impression you create among the average speaker when you say *ain't*;<sup>2</sup>
2. reasons for you to be aware that *ain't* has cultural connotations that you may be seen as appropriating if you overuse it out of affectation.

Anecdotally, many people I speak with here in Canada never use *ain't* except in dialect imitation or as a joke, often with an implied snicker at people who use it unironically.

I hope the above has been clear, but just in case: There is nothing wrong with *ain't* nor with how it's used in the sentence you found. But it's impossible to use without creating strong, mostly negative and usually stereotypical, impressions.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Some examples replacing do/does/does/did [language/content warning!]: "[he ain't go nowhere"](https://www.tiktok.com/@brehhhhhhh_/video/7096877984895880490?is_from_webapp=v1&item_id=7096877984895880490); ["he ain't go away"](https://lyrics.jspinyin.net/lyrics-longliveadamariz-he-aint-go-away/); ["he ain't want smoke"](https://www.tiktok.com/@bryce2jz/video/7102062785390972206?is_from_webapp=v1&item_id=7102062785390972206); ["he ain't want no smoke"](https://www.tiktok.com/@br0k3nvinyl_i/video/6998601266704239877?is_from_webapp=v1&item_id=6998601266704239877); ["you ain't gots to lie" and "he ain't want no mo"](https://genius.com/Beyonce-kitty-kat-lyrics); ["he ain't say his name in every song"](https://www.tiktok.com/@jaytaro15/video/7049848186546179374?is_from_webapp=v1&item_id=7049848186546179374); ["he ain't say shit"](https://www.tiktok.com/@berrymacockener4/video/7107389222352358702?is_from_webapp=v1&item_id=7107389222352358702); ["he ain't say nothin'"](https://www.lyrics.cat/lyrics+he+ain%E2%80%99t+say+nothin+he+just+blow+on+him); ["if he ain't said it, it ain't so"](https://m.facebook.com/LBS4PEACE/photos/a.299616854228453/594928184697317/?type=3&_rdr); ["ain't see it coming"](https://genius.com/King-von-aint-see-it-coming-lyrics); ["ain't grow up playing ball"](https://genius.com/Meek-mill-going-bad-lyrics); ["act like you ain't catch that"](https://open.spotify.com/track/6Igta4gsqJg998mGC3abTP); ["she ain't go to church"](https://genius.com/Blackbear-heartbroken-lyrics); ["you ain't go to church"](https://genius.com/Dj-khaled-work-for-it-lyrics); ["since Grandma died, I ain't go to church"](https://genius.com/Youngboy-never-broke-again-hold-your-own-lyrics) [ambiguous with "haven't gone"]; ["See, that why I ain't go to church"](https://libquotes.com/david-baldacci/quote/lbm8s1n); ["I ain't forget to pray but I ain't go to church"](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/35326253/Dababy/Tax+Time); ["I ain't go to church on Sunday but I still gotta talk the talk"](https://www.songteksten.nl/songteksten/1250278/yung-bleu/church.htm). Every one of these is culturally bound and should not be imitated in conversation, but it's well-established.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> But if your diction or accent gives you away as a non-native speaker, people will tend to regard such usage as more quaint than anything and may offer you corrections like "You really shouldn't use that," as one would for a child...</sub>

Comment: "he ain't go to church" doesn't sound quite right.   In this context, ain't is setting up the progressive tense, so "go" should be conjugated.  "he ain't gone to church" (past progressive), "he ain't goin' to church" (present progressive), or "he ain't gonna go to church" (future progressive).

Comment: @Faydey In those sentences it replaces *hasn't*, *isn't*, and *isn't* respectively, whereas in my example it replaces *doesn't*. As you can see in the linked article, *do* is an established replacement, although (as I mentioned) not every dialect uses *ain't* for all three categories. To me it does sound natural, but more restricted to AAVE rather than everyone in the broader Southern dialects.

Comment: As a native British English speaker I will say that "He ain't go to church" is 100% wrong... I've never heard anyone ever say that. "He ain't gone to church" maybe, but certainly not "He ain't go...". Also, `... am not ("he ain't a clown")` would be better written as `... am not ("I ain't a clown")` or even `... am not ("I ain't no clown")`- that is to say, keep it in the first person, rather than switching from first to third person, because this then becomes a confusing example.

Comment: @Greenonline As the Wikipedia article states, the *do* replacement is AAVE and Caribbean. Don't expect to hear it in the UK.

Comment: @Lukse Except from colored people, especially  with a Caribbean background ;-).

Comment: @Faydey "he ain't go to church" sounds wrong to me as well, while I ain't got no problem with the other two. And I can't pinpoint why. Is it because the other two are properties, while this one is about an action? Or is it the "go" I object to?

Comment: @StrangerToKindness It's the fact that it replaces "do" rather than "have" or "be".

Comment: There is some exception to the social stigma involved, when using certain stock phrases ("_ain't no such thing as a free lunch_" is the one that springs to mind.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica coloured is generally considered offensive in both US and British English (afaik, South Africa is the only country where it is considered neutral, but there it refers specifically to mixed race people and not non-white people in general)

Comment: I don't understand the example of replacing "am not": "he ain't a clown". Is there any dialect "he am" is grammatical? I'd say it's replacing "is not" in that context.

Comment: @Tristan Strangely enough, I wasn't aware of that. [M-W suggests](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colored#usage-1) to say "black" or "African-American" instead, both of which is probably not quite right if one wants to refer to non-white, non-Asian (to specify it *ex negativo*) immigrants from the Caribbean.

Comment: yeah. In the UK (where those are a more significant minority) tends to use "Afro-Caribbean" instead for that particular subgroup of black people, although IIRC some black people in the US object to the use of "afro" rather than "African" there

Comment: @WaterMolecule "as well as their other conjugations and contractions" was meant to cover that gap. But I suppose there's no reason not to align it with "I".

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica the generic is now "people/person of color"

Comment: @Greenonline As a native US English speaker, I can verify that I have heard "ain't go." Things and sayings can in fact exist even if you've never encountered them!

Comment: @Thierry "Things and sayings can in fact exist even if you've never encountered them!": Too true in my native German. Both ways: Things I commonly say are strange to others and vice versa. You think you know your language but no, Horatio.

Comment: Interestingly, this attitude of looking down upon the usage of the word is present in some other answers to this question.

Comment: @AdamBarnes interestingly, this attitude ain't present in the answers I'm seeing

Comment: @StrangerToKindness you don't gotta be lookin' too hard then.

Comment: Sorry, but it would be: I ain't gone to church.  I ain't going to work. "ain't go" is not grammatical with the range of usage for ain't, either among US southerners or Black English. Also, bear in mind, it is also used in the UK but I don't know the details on that. Also, it can be snobbery to use it if you are "educated".

Answer (score 23):

If you don't currently use the word *ain't*, you will have trouble using it and sounding natural.  It's part of dialectic English and its usage varies by locality.  Forcing the word *ain't* into your speech can be considered condescending to those who use it and can sound ignorant to those who don't.

Answer (score 6):

No. Don't use the word *ain't* in informal conversation, unless you come from a community that already regularly uses it in everyday conversation, and even then, don't use it in any sort of formal setting (especially work or education).

Stick to "have not" or "haven't".

Once you've REALLY mastered the complexities of English conversation you may choose to use it in limited circumstances, in a deliberately jokey, formulaic and memey way: "ain't nobody got time for that", but be extremely careful not to cause offence by seeming like you are mocking people who use the word regularly. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waEC-8GFTP4

Answer (score 4):

In formal English, the word *ain't* <s>ain't</s> isn't used at all.

In some varieties of *informal* English though, it's very commonly used.  Etymologically, *ain't* is a contraction for *am not*, but it can also be used for other negations of "to be" (*are not*, *is not*) or with other auxiliary verbs (*do not*, *have not*).

English speakers who don't normally say *ain't* may still use it in some situations:

- In fixed phrases, song lyrics, and pop culture references, e.g.:

  - "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."
  - "You ain't seen nothing yet."
  - "Say it ain't so."
  - "Ain't that a shame."
- As a deliberate form of lower-class reverse snobbery, to brag that "I ain't one of them Ivy League elitists."

But in the context of a school lesson, consider *ain't* to be always "incorrect".

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not. Ain't is non-standard English and should usually be avoided in formal writing. Some consider it as *low-class* English; however, this word has strong social connections namely with the black culture so I think 'ain't' is *dialectical* and *informal* rather than being low culture. I love using this word when speaking with friends.  Let's take a look at the history; in the past, it was used in these contexts:

- Lords and ladies were using this word in the spoken language in the Victorian era, so it had been associated with the upper class -but it is not anymore.
- Later, the contraction 'ain't' was used by some authors related to low-class characters in their books, for instance, by Charles Dickens.

  As we're online, it's beneficial to underline that I don't use 'low-class' here to insult anyone but my source and many other sources use this adjective; they don't use the adjective 'low-class' as a rude word either.

Now we can move on. The word 'ain't' can be used as a substitution for **'am not, are not, is not, have not, and has not.'** in informal contexts, unless you time travel to the Victorian era. There is also another word in English which is *hain't.* It's the nonstandard and the older use of have not/has not.

For further reading:

1. [Why is ain't such a controversial word?](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/aint-amnt-haint-baint/)
2. [Britannica Editor clarifies how and when to use 'ain't'](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/The-Word-Aint-when-to-use)
3. [The word 'ain't' explained by the BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv50.shtml)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, as a word or in "context" ... **Whichever** way you use that *non-word*, you're doing so at the very high risk of sounding like a person that **doesn't speak well**. And who wants to sound like that? Even people who use *slang*, can still speak well. I'm a thug who speaks nothing BUT slang - yet I can speak well. 'Ain't' isn't a word.

Comment: I don't like this answer (I'm not the downvoter though), but I laughed out loud at "I'm a thug."

Comment: I'm the downvoter. I downvoted because this answer is coming from an old-fashioned, prescriptive view of language that associates *value judgements* with language variations. We speak well, they speak poorly; we use real words, they use non-words; we were educated properly, they were educated badly. Linguistics is well past that, but English language education still has to catch up.